# TSQL QUERY to dump table into a file

Tags: sql

i have tried the following command to write a text file from a table:

```
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.table1" queryout "C:\employee.txt" -T -Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,'
```

No file is created, I am not sure why. Can anyone pls help?

I am not getting errors instead I get following messages:

`usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  NULL`

Comment: Does the SQL account have permissions on the servers C:\ drive (where that path is)

Comment: What results are you getting back when you run the command? (It should tell you whether it's worked or not, at least.) If it looks like it's worked, are you definitely checking the C:\ directory of the *server* "Servername", which is where that file will end up?

Comment: (Actually, I'm slightly wrong -- the file will end up on the C:\ drive of the server you're running the xp_cmdshell on, which might not necessarily be the same as the server you're querying, of course...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the query was correct -

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.table1" queryout "C:\employee.txt" -Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,'
```

while typing in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT studio I pressed enter after queryout so statement "C:\employee.txt" -Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,' was coming in next line. because of this I was not getting any error or output file

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a temp directory and add this to your path.  It could well be Windows protecting the root of the drive.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.table1" queryout "C:\TempDir\employee.txt" -T -Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,'
```

If the above statement works, then it is a permissions issue.